# jQuery Mobile range sliders not responsive enough

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi kind people of the internet,
I'm attempting to use the jQuery Mobile sliders (range) and while they work fairly well and are responsive on a desktop browser, they just don't seem to be very responsive or easy to use on an actual phone (such as an Android) when interacting with the internet web page.

The slider interaction using the touch screen on the Android is just very balky and difficult to use...I'm about to simply give up on using the slider (and use some other input widget, such as select pick-lists)

I wanted to make this post to see if anybody else is having the same challenges with range sliders, because if not, then it must be how I'm implementing the jQuery Mobile code for the range slider.

But if others are also having the same issues with jQuery Mobile sliders, I'm curious to see what other folks are doing to mitigate the issue?

Also: I have not yet attempted to wrap my app up using PhoneGap and import to my Android as an application...so I'm wondering if perhaps the range sliders would perform better if I made it into an app using PhoneGap?

thanks in advance

Update 11/4/2011 - here's a link to my test jqm page
http://www.simdock.com/TestJQueryMobile-Simdockv1.htm

Comment: Please edit your question and add some example code, maybe http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Which version of jQM are we talking about? What is more, are your sliders bound to some event like onchange?

Comment: Also. I'm fairly sure the sliders will perform worse if you wrap it with PhoneGap.

Comment: FYI: Slider is also rather sluggish on desktop when displayed in a long document with lots of elements.

Comment: Hi all...mucho thanks for the feedback. To Zancan, yes, I'm using the onchange event handler to catch the slider range change event and capture the value, and then perform some calculations and make some dynamic changes as the slider is being dragged/changed ...hmmmmm...I was sorta suspecting this might be the cause of balky performance (only on a phone)...but the point is that what a slider is good for? ...but I guess perhaps the phone, with it's still limited CPU might not be ready? But what are other developers doing in regards to the range/slider in jqm?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in jQuery Mobile: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4164