# Make jQuery mobile elements more responsive?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile, user-interface, cordova

I'm learning more about mobile development right now, but I'm wondering what some common methods are to increase the effectiveness of buttons, sliders, and interactive elements in jQuery mobile or similar frameworks. What is generally thought to be a better solution, increasing the area of the touch itself, or increasing the effective interactive area of the elements?

I also understand that Phonegap may or may not have a negative effect on wrapping these elements, but those thread are 2 years old now, I'd hope that those issues would be resolved, but can't find any documentation.

I've seen the [one related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983085/jquery-mobile-range-sliders-not-responsive-enough) to this, but nothing decent came of it.

Comment: *increase the effectiveness* jQuery Mobile elements are not good enough ?

Comment: For example, in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8xpV/7/, that slider requires the user on an iPhone to use razor-sharp precision to activate and grab the slider. I'm trying to figure out how to make it more friendly.

Comment: Um... how to load jsfiddle in mobile ? One solution I can think of is to make larger controls.

Comment: The fiddle isn't being loaded in mobile, that's an example of a slider I'm using in my Phonegap app. When I make test builds that run native on the phone, the slider functions poorly.

Answer (score 0):

I added this style (after jQM's css file ofcourse) and it became better for me when I tested it on android phones.

```
  a.ui-slider-handle-snapping {
     -webkit-transition: none;
     -moz-transition: none;
  }
```

Basically, removing the transitions help in this case. Hope this works out for you as well.